# Docker in LXD: can't communicate between services in swarm, but can in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-network, lxd

**update:** this apparrently happens because of the related Linux kernel details  (going to be fixed/improved in kernel v 5.3 https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/5193 ) please confirm in comment/answer if I grasped it correctly.

I am running docker swarm in lxd container, when trying to communicate between services in a docker swarm, I get the following error (deployed with `docker stack up -c docker-compose.yml test`):

```
$ docker exec -it <test_one_container_id> curl test_two"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to test_two port 80: Host is unreachable
```

same for ping. Services' virtual ip's are unpingable and curl don't work on them too.

But when I do the same when deploying this with `docker-compose up`, or `curl <container_id>`, then everything works as expected. Only services virtual ip's are unreachable. What is wrong in this setup?

I use the following simple docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  one:

    image: nginx:alpine
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
    networks:
        - test

  two:

    image: nginx:alpine
    deploy:
        replicas: 1
    networks:
        - test

networks:
    test:
```

The `test_test` network inspect:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "test_test",
        "Id": "q4jhj4lbmkae6salev8zyluf6",
        "Created": "2019-08-15T23:50:22.221701229+03:00",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.5.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.5.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2522e89c33b1220de9609d4502624696cf9fdbd7f98328f833d89ee999bc3953": {
                "Name": "test_one.1.bylmzvlkpcn4ud3eb4hmrn89y",
                "EndpointID": "37d35d8db8ba8f6227e7e11070d06c0ec87b4a0bb9acba7627e3e652e6972660",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:05:06",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.5.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "eecf6231cc889124ed8758c425020b782e1267ccfcccfe5af6843d832e3513b1": {
                "Name": "test_two.1.tngcq88ew9sff5lkrlorlmpxg",
                "EndpointID": "7f3036d0df48713e00f996ba8fbd4590b0aa7c33fc93fcdbb6aab8e0b28a1240",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:05:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.5.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-test_test": {
                "Name": "test_test-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "5c1e62ac350eaa10cbbe167ba27f974cba57b5bec1e1f2a72e7b22ad98efb2a3",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:05:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.5.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4102"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "b3f74b1318c9",
                "IP": "10.229.170.28"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Services inspects:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "wc0xjhib0wk9dwmr9sn18jy2e",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 319
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:50:24.266058906Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:50:24.271626665Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "test_one",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "nginx:alpine",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "nginx:alpine@sha256:482ead44b2203fa32b3390abdaf97cbdc8ad15c07fb03a3e68d7c35a19ad7595",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
                    },
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "q4jhj4lbmkae6salev8zyluf6",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "one"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            },
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "q4jhj4lbmkae6salev8zyluf6",
                    "Addr": "10.0.5.5/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]

[
    {
        "ID": "s40chkaulxblg4tb0rb1nhvc3",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 310
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:50:22.043647463Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2019-08-15T20:50:22.047243817Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "test_two",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "nginx:alpine",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "nginx:alpine@sha256:482ead44b2203fa32b3390abdaf97cbdc8ad15c07fb03a3e68d7c35a19ad7595",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "test"
                    },
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "ppc64le",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "s390x",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "q4jhj4lbmkae6salev8zyluf6",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "two"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            },
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "q4jhj4lbmkae6salev8zyluf6",
                    "Addr": "10.0.5.2/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: what is your core version ? run 'uname -mrs'

Comment: @RyabchenkoAlexander Linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64